# Javascript differences Desktop & Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I have this problem: there are two behaviors which works differently in mobile browser compared to Desktop browser.

First: In Desktop browser it is impossible to input any letter in the editable cell, because of the script below. However, in mobile I can set any letter and when press Enter it shows NaN in the cell.

Second: As you can see in the HTML code there is the event 'onClick', which select the value of the editable cell during the edit, so that the user can overwrite it without pressing Canc/Backspace. In mobile it selects the value too, problem it is that when tap the cell and don't edit anything but just press Enter again, it shows NaN and not the oldest not edited value.

Editable cell:

```
<td width="14%" class="text-center" id="Preleva" contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)"> @record.Preleva</td>
```

Script:

```
    $('td[id="Preleva"]').keypress(function(e) {
        if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Is it because [`Event#which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) is deprecated and is probably not supported on both?

Comment: @VLAZ it is supported on desktop chrome. Anyway i tried other options than event#which, but in mobile it still allows me to insert letters.

Answer (score 2):

The [document.execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) is deprecated and in some browsers could not work. If it is an input, you could do something like this (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067469/selecting-all-text-in-html-text-input-when-clicked) for more information):

```html
<input onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)" value="Sample Text" />
```

Moreover, the [e.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) is also deprecated and in some browsers could not work as well.

In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278648/alternative-for-events-deprecated-keyboardevent-which-property), you have a nice post about alternatives to the event which.

Moreover, you can find a nice alternative to `document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)` in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59881237/alternative-for-document-execcommandselectall-false-null)

Comment: Tested your code, however it doesn't work, in the console it gives the error:
"Cannot read property Length of undefined".
Problem might be that when i click on TD it has to convert the td on editable content, this is why there is the attribute contenteditable=true. 
Also, tested alternatives of e.which, like the keycode or keypress, on desktop chrome all of them works correctly, except on mobile browsers.

Comment: @staff614 if you run the snippet, it works. Which browser you are using?

Comment: Chrome in desktop and also in android. But i think the problem might be that I don't use the <input> tag but it is a <td> ?

Comment: The only way that I can see for this to work is to use `<input>`, showing/hidding each time the users click on the content. You can try playing with readonly input properties and chang the input layout to hide the border

Comment: @staff614 Maybe I'm wrong because i found out an alternative to `document.execCommnad`. Check out the edits that I made on my answer

Answer (score 0):

Solved by putting an  tag inside  and then managing everything on the  instead the , now it works perfectly in any device.