# Key press shows the key character

Tags: javascript

I have a search box which is by default not autofocused.
So i am putting a keypress event on the body i.e. when forward slash (/) is pressed the search box should be in focus. Although on key press it puts the search box in focus but also puts the "/" in the search box.

```
body.onkeypress = (e) => {
    if(e.which === 47) {
        searchInput.focus()
    }
}
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Not quite sure, but I think you have to change the default behavior of the `keyPress` to avoid this.

You could try to do : `e.prevenDefault()` in your function and return `false` at the end so that the real behavior is not triggered

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: You can clear the input field after focusing

Comment: Thanks for this it is working now, but it now refrains from registering any other key stroke as in the search box is in focus but I cannot type anything in it.

Comment: you'll need to show more code for context

Comment: `event.which` is deprecated. see: [Alternative for event's deprecated KeyboardEvent.which property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278648/alternative-for-events-deprecated-keyboardevent-which-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use preventdefault to prevent the '/' from being typed.

Make sure you do this in your if statement, otherwise all characters get blocked.

```
body.onkeypress = (e) => {
    if(e.which === 47) {
        e.preventDefault()
        searchInput.focus()
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

```
  <body id="body">
  <input type="text" id="elementid" />
</body>
<script>
  document.onkeypress = (e) => {
    if (e.which === 47) {
      document.getElementById("elementid").focus();
      setTimeout(() => {
        str = document.getElementById("elementid").value = document
          .getElementById("elementid")
          .value.slice(0, -1);
      });
    }
  };
</script>
```